# Picking image and uploading problem on Android (Unity + Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

My project involves using Unity + Firebase and is exported to Android. I'm using plugin "Unimgpicker" to pick the image from the device and then I want to upload it to Firebase.
Everything works perfectly fine in Unity.
Picking image works on android, but the image doesn't get uploaded.

I tried uploading the image.texture -> Texture2D textureToUpload = imageToUpload.texture as Texture2D, also worked perfectly fine in Unity. I changed the code to involve the path to the file, but it didn't help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Kakera;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Firebase;
using Firebase.Storage;
using Firebase.Database;

public class ImagePicker : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private Unimgpicker imagePick;

    [SerializeField]
    RawImage image;

    [SerializeField]
    RawImage imageToUpload;

    Texture2D imageToUploadTexture;

    [SerializeField]
    Button uploadButton;

    [SerializeField]
    Text errorText;


        void Awake()
        {
            // Unimgpicker returns the image file path.
            imagePick.Completed += (string path) =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(LoadImage(path, image));
                StartCoroutine(UploadAndroid(path));
            };
        }

        public void OnPressShowPicker()
        {
            // With v1.1 or greater, you can set the maximum size of the image
            // to save the memory usage.
            imagePick.Show("Select Image", "unimgpicker", 1024);
        }

        private IEnumerator LoadImage(string path, RawImage output)
        {
            var url = "file://" + path;
            var www = new WWW(url);
            yield return www;

            var texture = www.texture;
            if (texture == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Failed to load texture url:" + url);
            }

            output.texture = texture;

        }


    public IEnumerator UploadAndroid(string path){
        Debug.Log("Started");

        if(path != string.Empty){
            var url = "file://" + path;
            var www = new WWW(url);
            yield return www;

            var texture = www.texture;

            Texture2D  imageToUpload = texture as Texture2D;

            var bytesToSend = imageToUpload.EncodeToPNG();
            Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
            Firebase.Storage.StorageReference storage_ref = storage.GetReferenceFromUrl("gs://detectivepigv1.appspot.com");
            Firebase.Storage.StorageReference images_ref = storage_ref.Child("Images/Test6.png");

            images_ref.PutBytesAsync(bytesToSend).ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>{
                if(task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled){
                    Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                    errorText.text = task.Exception.ToString();
                }
                else{
                    Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
                    string downloadUrl = images_ref.GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();
                    Debug.Log("Download at: " + downloadUrl);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Choose Photo first");
        }

    }
}
```

I don't get any error messages. Will be extremely grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add any comment on your post that's why I am suggesting you an answer. 
First of all, check out the path of storage that is it correct and the image is being loaded on the output texture in your first callback function "LoadImage(path, image)". If the path is correct then I assume there is some issue in appending the path with the file in your code

var url = "file://" + path 
log the url and to check it.

Secondly, if you have the image in texture format then you don't need to fetch the file from the storage (heavy process), you can upload the image by using byte conversion of texture, below is the code:

```
Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage storage   = Firebase.Storage.FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
byte[] bytes = imageToUpload.EncodeToJPG(); // your texture image


Firebase.Storage.StorageReference path_reference =
                                    storage.GetReference("_img.jpg");


    path_reference.PutBytesAsync(bytes)
                                    .ContinueWith ((task) => {
                                        if (task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled) {
                                            Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
                                            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                        }
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                                        path_reference .GetDownloadUrlAsync ().ContinueWith ((task1) =>
                                                {
                                                    if (task1.IsFaulted || task1.IsCanceled) {
                                                        Debug.Log(task1.Exception.ToString());
                                                        Debug.Log("Oops!!!\nError in uploading image");
                                                        // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                                                    } 
                                                    else 
                                                    {
                                                        var uri = task1.Result.OriginalString;
                                                        print("uri: "+uri);



                            }
                });

        }
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem. 
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! The image from the path gets loaded into texture and shows in the Android and Unity alike without a problem this is why I'm so confused haha :)

Comment: then you can use image bytes conversion to upload the image. my above posted code is working fine for me :) you can use that

Comment: Unfortunately just like before - in unity everything works, upload doesnt work in Android. I'm starting to think I might have problems with SDK. I installed Analytics, Storage and Database, added app In Firebase console and put the json file in the project. I feel like I'm missing something. Anyway, once again thank you for the help! :)

Comment: Now everything works fine. I am able to, both, pick image and upload it. I didn't change anything.

Comment: Good for you :)